# How to include a javascript (not from a gem) in a rails project in a specific order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a script called editor.js that relies on external scripts from a cdn.  I am including the cdn scripts by using rails javascript tags and placing them in the main layout.

I need editor.js to be loaded after the cdn scripts.  To achieve this locally I have just included a separate js tag referencing the editor.js.  The editor.js script is located in assets/javascripts directory.

Deployed as so, asset pipeline does not finish including all of the scripts and seems to choke.  I cannot simply include it in the manifest because it loads before the cdn scripts.  How do I achieve this in production?

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to include `editor.js` to assets precompile config?. If you had not, you can add this line to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( editor.js )
```

This will allow you to include a separate js tag referencing the `editor.js` file.

Comment: Including this locally works however but when its deployed it does not.

Comment: Can you more specific, where and how do you deploy your app? And on production, how the header of your page look like?